# Did the actor for "woman with stroller" change between shots in "Ruby and Quentin" (2003)?

Tags: casting

In the beginning (around minutes 10-11) of "Ruby and Quentin" (2003), there is a robbery.  The armored vehicle is initially "incapacitated" by a stroller with a bomb thrown at it by a man disguised as a woman.

However, if my "biological visual capture-and-analysis tools" (eyes) work fine, before the disguised man actually starts to cross the street (casually pushing the stroller, of course), the stroller seems to be actually pushed by a young woman. I looked as carefully as I could at the face and at the hands, and I think I am not wrong.

**Can anyone please confirm this? Was there an actor change?** I did not notice anything in the credits about this.

If yes, is the woman some known actress (maybe doing some uncredited cameo), or not?

Comment: @Laurel: tnx for the edit. As I wrote late at night, I obviously made a lot of mistakes :D